# Can PMD be used to derive IntelliSense information?

Tags: pmd

(This is a niche technical question, but the end result might be of broader interest, so I'm asking here, but am happy to take the discussion over to email if it's not worth a SO exchange.)

**Background:** I'm currently using PMD to drive style-checking on my students' submitted homeworks.  This is a combination of PMD and CheckStyle, and outputs in a custom format, so I'm already using PMD programmatically rather than from the command line.  Once the style checkers have been run, I display the output in a webapp that we use for course management and homework grading.

I'd like to enhance my webapp to allow jump-to-definition sorts of interactions, as an IDE does.  To do that, I need more precise output than e.g. [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) produces.  Since PMD already does Java parsing and type-resolution, it seems conceivable that PMD could be used to identify all names in a file and figure out their binding sites.

**Approach so far:**  I've figured out a way to run the parser, the `NameResolution` facade, the `Symbol` facade, the `DataFlow` facade, the `TypeResolution` facade, and `Multifile` facade, as in the `SourceCodeProcessor` logic.  (I don't know if I need all of these, but I presume it can't hurt to run them...)  I've tried to define my own AST visitor whose core logic is

- visit `ASTName` nodes
- get their `NameDeclaration`s
- record the source location of the declarations and the source location of the nodes, as a def->use pair

**Problems/Questions:**

1. Despite rigging the auxClasspath to include the right jars, name resolution sometimes fails to resolve e.g. `assertEquals` to `org.junit.Assert.assertEquals`, or other static imports.  I've traced the execution into the `ClassTypeResolver`, and it seems to be finding the `org.junit.Assert` class, but when my visitor gets to run, the relevant `ASTName` nodes have a null NameDeclaration and a null Type.
2. I don't understand how to ensure that symbols from other files are reliably detected.  I think it's a set-the-right-classpath-and-make-sure-the-files-are-all-compiled sort of thing, but I can't quite explain the failures I sometimes see.
3. Why do `ASTName`s sometimes consist of dotted access paths, e.g. `someObject.someMethod` being treated as a single `ASTName`?  How could I get the name resolution for the two parts independently?
4. Are there any other visitors I need to run, before attempting to get reliable name and type information?
5. (Feature request) Would this potentially be something that would be worth PMD doing as built-in functionality?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Definitely a little out of scope, so maybe going to the PMD devel mailing list, or just emailing us maintainers directly would be best.

Nontheless, as no-one seems to have had a problem with the question so far I'll answer as completely as I may.

1. the type resolution code attempts to mark what each node's type is. For method calls `foo(bar, baz)`, that means looking for whatever `foo`'s return type is (not the type that defines `foo`). For `Assert.assertEquals` the return type is `void` so ideally that's what you should see. There are some caveats non-the-less. This particular area of PMD's typeresolution is still incomplete (we resolve just fine the simpler scenarios, but struggle on hard ones where type inference comes into play). Any bug reports / PRs on this area are greatly appreciated.
2. Symbols from the symbol table or types? Remember symbol table is still single-file. Types aren't, but that's why we need the project's own compiled classes to be in the `auxclasspath` too.
3. Legacy… We have plans to change it one way or the other (see [#497](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/issues/497)), but doing so is a hard breaking change on how the AST is built, which in turn means all rules using `ASTName` (both within PMD and built by users) will most probably stop working altogether… please jump in with any feedback or ideas.
4. No, you are actually running more than you need. With just symbol table and type resolution you should be good (in that order!)
5. Maybe… you could draft an RFC issue on PMD to better discuss possible use cases… Non the less, other than wether we expose the symbol table somehow, most of the other things you are trying to do are things we care about.